# How to run PJSUA CLI command in telnet?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I build PJSIP and able to build PJSUA using swig for Android, I want to execute the Android App using telnet commands. I have enabled telnet and tried "call new sip:localhost" and "--use-cli". I am getting "Invalid Command" message in telnet. Please help if any one made done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For configuring Telnet client on Windows7 follow below link:

```
  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx
```

After telnet configuration, start command prompt.
On command prompt, enter command as follows:

```
  C:\Users\User-name> telnet 192.168.4.101 2323
```

Where 192.168.4.101 is your IP address that you see after starting pjsua android app's screen and 2323 is telnet's port number. If it works, you will get result as follows:

```
   localhost>
```

For calling enter command as follows:

```
   localhost> call new sip:192.168.4.109
```

Where 192.168.4.109 is IP address of another telnet client.

Hope it helps...